# Firefox X11 in Mac OSX Moutain Lion 10.8

Tags: firefox, selenium, x11, osx-mountain-lion, headless

We are running selenium tests (firefox automation) and I would like to forward it to the background using the headless gem. (https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless).

Everything was working well on lion but since the removal of X11 in moutain lion, I can't get the firefox X11 version working. I've tried XQuartz with no success.

Do you know a way to install Firefox X11 in Mac OSX Moutain Lion 10.8 ? Thanks!

Using :

- Firefox 16
- Watir Webdriver (ruby selenium binding)
- XQuartz 2.7.4
- Max OSX 10.8.2

Comment: Trying to do `sudo port install firefox-x11` got : 

--->  Applying patches to firefox-x11
--->  Configuring firefox-x11
--->  Building firefox-x11
Error: org.macports.build for port firefox-x11 returned: command execution failed
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port firefox-x11 failed
`

Answer (score -2):

I would not prefer to use xvfb anymore. Try to use phantomjs as your driver if you want to go headless.